# C++ Console Application1.exe has triggered a breakpoint,Visual Studio 2015.Array and random numbers

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to run this code in `VS 2015 c++`, but I have this problem: while getting the correct answer, I also get the error `C++ Console Application1.exe has triggered a breakpoint`. My task is to randomly choose 10 numbers between 1 and 50, show these numbers and sort them by odd and even numbers. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
void main() {
    const int size = 10;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[size], odd = 0, even = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 50 + 1;
        cout << arr[i] << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
    int *arrOdd = new int[odd];
    int *arrEven = new int[even];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            arrEven[even] = arr[i];
            even++;
        }
        else
        {
            arrOdd[odd] = arr[i];
            odd++;
        }
    }
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            cout << "arrEven = " << arrEven[a] << endl;
            a++;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "arrOdd = " << arrOdd[b] << endl;
            b++;
        }

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int arr[size], odd = 0, even = 0;
//odd's and event's dont change
//...
int *arrOdd = new int[odd];
int *arrEven = new int[even];
```

So you are trying to allocate arrays with 0 length